# Three different Eclipse versions all crash with BadWindow on 15.04

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a complete fresh install of XUbuntu 15.04 on a Dell Laptop with an Intel Graphics-Card. I installed eclipse (see below which versions I tried and from where) and I'm able to start it. But randomly after some seconds to some minutes, eclipse crashes: A dialog-window is shown with the following content:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Xms80m
-Xmx2048m
-jar /home/dominik/Applications/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /home/dominik/Applications/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.2.v20150204-1700/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/dominik/Applications/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/dominik/Applications/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316/eclipse_1607.so
-startup /home/dominik/Applications/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 38000f
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Xms80m
-Xmx2048m
-jar /home/dominik/Applications/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

On a console-window, where eclipse was launched, I see the following additional information:

```
The program 'Eclipse' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 28725 error_code 3 request_code 3 minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

I tried the following versions of eclipse (all of them in the linux 64bit variant)

1. 4.4.2 (the most recent) downloaded from eclipse.org
2. 4.3.2 downloaded from eclipse.org
3. 3.8 directly installed from the "eclipse" ubuntu package

I also tried each of these eclipse with:

1. OpenJDK 7 (so the openjdk-7-jdk (+jre) packages)
2. Oracle Java 7 (so the oracle-java7-installer package)

All combitions crash.

I also tried increasing the `MaxPermSize` what some bug reports recommended, didn't help.

The machine is rock solid otherwise, so I don't think it is an hardware-error.

Where can one start to search for an error? I only found stone-age bug-reports on both eclipse and ubuntu, non of them seem applicable.

Comment: You should at least try IntelliJ IDEA unless you really need Eclipse :) It just works.

Comment: Actually, that is what I'm doing now, but still I'm interested what the reason is after I spent hours debugging it.

Comment: Bugs need to be reported on launchpad. Please see:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 1):

> Where can one start to search for an error?

There are strong indications that this is related to xfce 4.12 which is used in Xubuntu 15.04. There are several other people getting the same error messages (including me) and all of them have in common that they use xfce 4.12 as their desktop environment. (Some of them posted it here as an answer, but it was deleted although it was valuable information)
[Here](https://forum.xfce.org/index.php) you can find a forum where you can ask for technical support and [here](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/) you can report a bug. I hope this answers the question.

> ...but still I'm interested what the reason is after I spent hours debugging it.

The reason for this issue *might be* that Xubuntu 15.04 upgraded to xfce 4.12 which *may* contain a bug.

However, please note that this is not conformed to be a bug! There is no reason to delete this question, because it could also be caused by a misconfiguration.